# How would I filter using filterBy for a multiple values selected and use mapBy to manipulate the array?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

on my template I do have a dropdown that may select a multiple values Example, `zoneNameOne`, `zoneNameTwo`. My `component.js` has a code that would filter a records based on the multiple values that had been selected from the dropdown.

```
jobOrderCityNames: computed('selectedZoneOrCityName', 
 'jobOrders.@each.zoneName', 'jobOrders.@each.cityName', function() {
  let selectedZoneOrCityName = this.get('selectedZoneOrCityName');
  if (selectedZoneOrCityName) {
    return this.get('jobOrders').filterBy('zoneName', selectedZoneOrCityName).mapBy('cityName');
   } else {
    return [];
  }
}),
```

The jobOrders return a array of objects below.
  `[{id: 123, type: "job-orders",…}, {id: 124, type: "job-orders",…}]`

My problem: `I can't filter the array of objects on a multiple values selected from the dropdown. Please see the code above`

My question: `How can I filter the array of objects on a multiple values and mapBy the property name?`

Please help me, any response is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `filterBy`, you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Then you can check if either of any item's `zoneName` or `cityName` properties are equal to your `selectedZoneOrCityName` for filtering. So your code will be like:

```
return this.get('jobOrders').filter((jobOrder) =>{
    return (jobOrder.zoneName === selectedZoneOrCityName) || (jobOrder.cityName === selectedZoneOrCityName);
  }
).mapBy('cityName');
```

Comment: You could also use computed macros. This would make the code more readable IMO.